# Rounding up/down to number

Tags: java

I have a bunch of integers i need to round up or down, to the closest value which divides by 25.

For instance:

417 rounds up to 425

405 rounds down to 400

Comment: Try `(int)(Math.round(x / 25.0) * 25)`

Comment: That worked out Tomasz! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int roundedValue = (valueToRound + 12) / 25 * 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Devide the number by 25, cast it to an integer then multiply it to 25 back
- Or Take it's value and remove the result of the value %25
- Add 25/2 to the value prior to anything in order to round to the nearest

  function roundTo(value, rounding)
  {
  temp = value + rounding/2;
  return temp - temp%rounding;
  }